# Customize NER in StanfordNLP Server

Tags: stanford-nlp

**Hi, I'm trying to add additional entities to current default rules. It worked on txt.file in stanfordNLP, but when I applied in python using stanfordNLPServer, it could not overwrite the default rules.**

I'm using NLTK wrapper of coreNLP in Python, and the input text is a column from a dataframe. The default rules worked well, but could not add customized rules.

**Java command that worked for StanfordCoreNLP:**

'java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.regexner.mapping extra.txt -file example.txt -outputFormat text'

**But it failed when I ran the following StanfordCoreNLPServer command:**

'java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.regexner.mapping extra.txt -status_port 9000 -port 9000 -timeout 90000 &'

My guess is that coreNLPServer cannot customize entities yet, but not sure about it. Really appreciate it if anyone can help with this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-serverProperties` option and set up a file with all of the properties you want for the pipeline.

You can't submit pipeline properties to the server directly.

So as an example, make a file called `server.props`.

In that file put your properties:

```
annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner
ner.additional.regexner.mapping = extra.txt
```

And then run this command:

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000 -serverProperties server.props
```